# Java date and age

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat, swingx

I am using a JXDatepicker to get the birth date of a person, and what i have to do is set another JXDatepicker with the retirement date. So the idea here is to get the year of the birth date and to increment it with one year in a loop until the "person" reaches 60 years old and keep the same day and month of birth.. Or i think that's what i have to do. but i can't seem to find how to use the Calendar classes nor the DateFormat classes to do this calculation, i tried different things but nothing works, the closest i got is the date 01/01/1970, which can't be the person's retirement date since the birth date i'm testing is always in 2014 so it should be 2074.

So how can i do the calculation? I'd be grateful if someone could give me an example on how to do it.

(It might seem that i didn't do enough researches, but i did, and i don't find why i would mention what i found  since it didn't help me)

Comment: You should show what you've *tried* so we can help you fix that rather than starting from scratch. (You shouldn't be using `DateFormat` to do *any* calculations... that's just for string formatting/parsing.)

Comment: If you're interested in doing date calculations in Java, you should probably take a look at JodaTime or, if Java 8 is available, the new `java.time` API.

Comment: @Smallhacker, yeah i tried that, but i didn't know how to use it since i have a problem understanding the oracle docs.. but now the answer given to me worked, so thank you all anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't write any loop to add 60 years to your date. 
You can get a selected date from your JXDatePicker and do it like that:

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 60);
final Date retirementDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Thank you but now i feel stupid :p! The problem was that i didn't know about the call.add() method or at least i didn't know how to use it. and now it just worked... something as simple as this took me two days -_-! I really appreciate it. I'll accept your answer as soon as i can, and sorry i can't vote, i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth would you have to add 1 in a loop 60 times? Why don't you just add 60?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args){

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime())); //prints 05/14/2014

        c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 60);
        System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime())); //prints 05/14/2074
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i become stupid sometimes -_-! now that i think of it i feel ashamed :p! but thank you anyway.